# Hi, I have one for any DBA's out there about the superuser account.

Tags: sql, database

Is there any database that comes with NO default superuser account, or is there a way to have no superuser at all. I have extensively researched this for the past week and I can find nothing on this topic. My manager is keen on having no superuser by the time the system I'm working on is in deployment, however I feel this is not possible?

Comment: Set random password for superuser and throw it out. But good luck then.

Comment: Your question should rather read. How do I properly audit use of superuser account.

Comment: This is not a good idea ..

Comment: @DonalLane That is quite the understatement right there! What would you do if something went wrong with the database? How would you import/export, create new databases/tables, monitor, optimise or even fix corrupted tables?

Comment: I'm not going to implement anything like this I am just looking for scenarios of what can be done regardless of risk. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

With MS SQL Server you can install it to use windows accounts. So you set up superuser tied to windows account. After deployment just disable this account in Windows and you are good to go.
To make sure it works properly you enable audit on user enabling, so you know when someone tries to enable the user account and use it to access DB.
It is bad idea to remove sysadmin completely because you might run into lot of troubles in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just yesterday our intern set up SQLServer and didn't add a database administrator at the relevant step in the setup, so it installed but was rather useless..

Questions like this are from a similar side of the fence:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11299/how-to-add-sysadmin-to-user-in-sql-server-2008-when-no-sysadmin-accounts-exist